# Why are some of my elements not displaying in my final output?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to set my values for my variables to be displayed in my output, but only one variable's value is managed to display in my output. Is it because there is some error in my get, set method in my class defining?

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;


using namespace std;

class Employee
{
    private:
        string name;
        int idNumber;
        string department;
        string position;

    public:
        void setEmployee(string nam, int id, string dep, string pos);

        string getEmployee();





};

void Employee::setEmployee(string nam, int id, string dep, string pos)
{
    name = nam;
    idNumber = id;
    department = dep;
    position = pos;
}

string Employee::getEmployee()
{
    return name, idNumber, department, position;
}


int main()
{
    Employee emp;
    cout << "Name \t" << "ID Number \t" << "Department \t" << "Position" << endl;

    emp.setEmployee("Susan", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President");

    cout << emp.getEmployee();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To receive help on your question, you must post your code! If we can not see the code, there is no way to know what is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
return name, idNumber, department, position;
```

In C++ a function can return only one single value.
Your `getEmpoyee()` function is defined to return one single string, and that is exactly what it does.

Using comma the way you do is a valid syntax so it compiles, but it does not do what you think. Everything after `name` is simply ignored.

The proper way is to create separate get functions for all fields.

It is also recommended to use separate set functions, each setting only one field.
If you want to initialize all fields at once, you should do it in the constructor.

Example:

```
class Employee
{
    private:
        string name;
        int idNumber;
        string department;
        string position;

    public:
        //this is a constructor, it has no return type and same name as the class
        Employee(string nam, int id, string dep, string pos);

        string getEmployee();
};


Employee::Employee(string nam, int id, string dep, string pos)
{
    name = nam;
    idNumber = id;
    department = dep;
    position = pos;
}

int main() {
    Employee emp("Susan", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President");
}
```

Comment: can i see an example of how to do it in a constructor?

Comment: @JagdeeshSandhu I added an example. It is similar to how you use `setEmployee` now, you just add the parameters to different function and do it when you create the object, not after.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I'm curious to know about something. i notice that you have added constructor with all the parameters in it, when I compile it, will it have an error because the system needs a default constructor?

Comment: @JagdeeshSandhu the "system" does not need anything. It all depends on your code. If you do not have default constructor, you will not be able to create objects of this class without providing parameters, but for this example it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
return name, idNumber, department, position;
```

Will return only name. If you want to return one string containing all values, you have to concatenate the values into one string, e.g. by using the + operator.

Comment: I tried concatenating the return values, it still shows error